# Redis::ConnectionError on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I setup Redis on heroku and it's working fine but sometime I'm getting error in NEW RELIC.

> Redis::ConnectionError > Connection reset by peer

See screenshots
[image]

Not able to understand why this Redis lost his connection. This error comes randomly. sometime it's working and sometime i'm getting this error. I have 1 **Standard 2x Dyno** on heroku.

Detail Log : http://awesomescreenshot.com/01d6834i3c

Comment: Check your heroku logs. It may be that it's being closed because you've exceeded your Redis plan limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will magically fix itself when you upgrade to Sidekiq 4.2.9.

Comment: Thank you. I check the last 2 days history. I'm not getting the error.

Comment: Do you have any idea for 2nd error that comes in the screenshot - Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors